# C output formatting using tabs

Tags: c

My code

```
int main(void){
    int arr1[6],arr2[6];
    const char * weather[] = {"January","February","March","April","May","June"};

    printf("Enter 6 numbers for Arr1");  //get values for arr1
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
        //avg2 = intarr[i] + avg2;
    }

    printf("Enter 6 numbers for Arr1");  //get values for arr2
    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr2[i]);
        //avg2 = intarr[i] + avg2;
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){ . //print values for arr1
        printf("\n%s        ",weather[i]);
        printf("|");
        for(int k = 0;k<arr1[i];k++){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n      |");
        for(int k = 0;k<arr2[i];k++){
            printf("!");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
[https://i.imgur.com/GymyHqD.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvst1.png)
I'm confused on how to get the February line to format correctly. As shown, it is off by the others by one tab. Is there an easy way to format this?

Comment: There is no `tab` character in your code.

Comment: I was using actual tabs, very new to c and programming in general. I wasn't aware of other methods.

Comment: If you put a tab in a string, use `"\t"` in C code; do not type a literal tab (control-I) into the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just `printf` the string left justified with a length modifier.

```
printf("%-20s", weather[i]);
```

Will print `weather[i]` :

- `-`  makes it left justified
- `20` makes the length of the field to 20 characters. Empty places are filled with spaces.

Comment: Works great, thank you for letting me know. I'll accept your answer when it allows me(in 3 mins.)

Comment: The longest month name in English is September, with 9 characters; the 20 could probably be 9 or 10.